# Sub query to search for value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

There are two tables, `hotel` and `hotel_booking`. The `hotel_booking` table has two columns:

```
hotel_id
date_booked
```

The `hotel_id` goes from `1-10`, and for each one, a date will be entered if it has been booked.

**I need to search for all the hotel_id's that have not been booked for a particular date.** I have tried using `NOT IN`, but it returns all the dates that do not match the one entered, so does not equal to.

This doesn't work, but this is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM hotel_booking WHERE date != "29/01/2014"
```

I know I have to do a sub query of some sort, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: what is the data type of date and how these are stored ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT h.hotel_id
FROM hotel h
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
              FROM hotel_booking b
              WHERE date = "29/01/2014"
             ) excluded
  ON excluded.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
WHERE excluded.hotel_id IS NULL
```

Or also this one:

```
SELECT hotel_id
FROM hotel h
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM hotel_booking hb
                  WHERE hb.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
                  AND date = "29/01/2014")
```

Comment: This works if I enter a date in a string, but when I ask the user to input a date it outputs the hotel_id's from 1-10. Have I missed something?

Comment: Fixed it, just had to pass it through as a string

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM hotel_booking WHERE date != "2014-01-29"

Comment: How is copying sql directly from the post an answer?